# PHP webservice Language translator

Tags: php, web-services, translation

I have an requirement to translate an web service response from English to some other language   like Spanish,French etc. Here I fetch mysql data as an my web service response in english, so here i need to convert it into specific language without using google-translator.Can you provide me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: What about Bing http://www.som3on3.com/programming/php/php-bing-translate-api/ ?

Comment: @Bogdan Burim, Can you provide me some code snippet to convert an text below like $translator ='Welcome to php'; so here I need to convert this $translator value to specific language. I'm new to php environment.

Comment: @BogdanBurim, I think it's an paid version api, i'm in need of open source.

Comment: See here http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis

Answer (score 0):

Put your API ID instead of YoutApiIDHere:

```
<?php

echo translate('Hello World', 'en', 'fr');

function translate($text, $from, $to) {

 $data = file_get_contents('http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=YoutApiIDHere&Sources=Translation&Version=2.2&Translation.SourceLanguage=' . $from . '&Translation.TargetLanguage=' . $to . '&Query=' . urlencode($text));

 $translated = json_decode($data);

 if (sizeof($translated) > 0) {

 if (isset($translated->SearchResponse->Translation->Results[0]->TranslatedTerm)) {

 return $translated->SearchResponse->Translation->Results[0]->TranslatedTerm;

 } else {

 return false;

 }

 } else {

 return false;

 }

}

?>
```